# PHP convert remaining seconds (from now) into date

Tags: php, date, seconds

Good morning, guys. I was just thinking about the small PHP crawler, that could browse my 2 favourite websites and show me some info about auctions from 1 category.
I haven't started to write anything, because I stuck on the remaining time that every auction has. I want to snow only the date, when the auction ends. But these sites provide me only  a seconds (or miliseconds), that remains from now to the end.
How to convert these seconds into normal date like 2011-08-24? I appreciate any advice.

George

Comment: subtract remaining from current timestamp, then use date() to format

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do `$date =  time() + $seconds;`. Now $date holds the date on which the auction will end. You can output that in a nice way with `date()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
//watch for time zone issues
echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A',time()+$remaining);

+ not - sorry
```

Comment: +1 for considering timezones. Though, in this context with a relative time, it is not relevant. But people usually don't pay attention to that and then complain.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo date('Y-m-d',time() - $remaining_seconds);
```

This will format your date as YYYY-MM-DD as you requested.